# Ignore property based on where it's referenced under

Tags: java, properties, jackson, parent

I have a Java Object which has attributes property that needs to be ignored based on its outer object.
For e.g. Book class has a property called attributes. When this is referenced under Box Class I want 'attributes' to be ignored but not when it's referenced inside Case Class.

Not sure if we have a way to do that using Jackson.

Comment: Did you take a look at the @JsonIgnore annotation?

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/issues/78